# How to extract a JSON value in Hive

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I Have a JSON string that is stored in a single cell in the DB corresponding to a parent ID

```
{"profileState":"ACTIVE","isDefault":"true","joinedOn":"2019-03-24T15:19:52.639Z","profileType":"ADULT","id":"abc","signupDeviceId":"1"}||{"profileState":"ACTIVE","isDefault":"true","joinedOn":"2021-09-05T07:47:00.245Z","imageId":"19","profileType":"KIDS","name":"Kids","id":"efg","signupDeviceId":"1"}
```

Now I want to use the above JSON to extract the id from this. Let say we have data like

```
Parent ID  |  Profile JSON
1          |  {profile_json} (see above string)
```

I want the output to look like this

```
Parent ID  |  ID
1          |  abc
1          |  efg
```

Now, I've tried a couple of iterations to solve this

***First Approach:***

```
select
    get_json_object(p.profile, '$$.id') as id,
    test.parent_id
    
    from (
        select split(
                regexp_replace(
                    regexp_extract(profiles, '^\\[(.+)\\]$$',1),
                '\\}\\,\\{', '\\}\\|\\|\\{'),
                '\\|\\|') as profile_list,
                parent_id ,
                
        from source_table) test
        lateral view explode(test.profile_list) p as profile
)
```

But this is returning the `id` column as having NULL values. Is there something I'm missing here.

***Second Approach:***

```
with profiles as(
  select        regexp_replace(
                    regexp_extract(profiles, '^\\[(.+)\\]$$',1),
                '\\}\\,\\{', '\\}\\|\\|\\{') as profile_list,
                parent_id
                
        from source_table
)      

SELECT
  get_json_object (t1.profile_list,'$.id')
FROM profiles t1
```

The second approach is only returning the first id (`abc`) as per the above JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this. Was using a extract $ in the First Approach

```
select
get_json_object(p.profile, '$.id') as id,
test.parent_id

from (
    select split(
            regexp_replace(
                regexp_extract(profiles, '^\\[(.+)\\]$$',1),
            '\\}\\,\\{', '\\}\\|\\|\\{'),
            '\\|\\|') as profile_list,
            parent_id ,
            
    from source_table) test
    lateral view explode(test.profile_list) p as profile
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this in apache hive v4.

Data

```
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|                    data                    | parent_id  |
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| {"profileState":"ACTIVE","isDefault":"true","joinedOn":"2019-03-24T15:19:52.639Z","profileType":"ADULT","id":"abc","signupDeviceId":"1"}||{"profileState":"ACTIVE","isDefault":"true","joinedOn":"2021-09-05T07:47:00.245Z","imageId":"19","profileType":"KIDS","name":"Kids","id":"efg","signupDeviceId":"1"} | 1.0              |
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Sql

```
select pid,get_json_object(expl_jid,'$.id') json_id from 
(select  parent_id pid,split(data,'\\|\\|') jid  from tabl1)a 
lateral view explode(jid) exp_tab as expl_jid;

+------+----------+
| pid  | json_id  |
+------+----------+
| 1.0  | abc      |
| 1.0  | efg      |
+------+----------+
```